# Creating areas in ASP.NET MVC 5 monodevelop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mono, monodevelop

I'm developing a MVC 5 project using monodevelop 5.9.6 on linux ubuntu, however IDE doesn't show the option add ... Areas for the project. ¿It is possible to configure monodevelop to support areas or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no tooling support for Areas in MonoDevelop so you will need to create them yourself. MonoDevelop supports creating controllers and views.